# How do I construct a JSON message to send with Amazon-SES?

Tags: json, bash, email, amazon-ses

I'm running into the following error when I try to send an email via Amazon-SES:

```
Error parsing parameter '--raw-message': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I don't understand where I am messing up the JSON message...

This is the bash script I am using:

```
echo '{\"Data\": 
"Subject:'${SUBJECT}'\\n
MIME-Version: 1.0\n
Content-type: Multipart/Mixed; 
boundary=\"NextPart\"\\n\\n--NextPart\\n
Content-Type: text/plain\\n\\n'${BODY}'
\\n\\n--NextPart
\\nContent-Type:'${ATTACHMENT_TYPE}';
\nContent-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=\"'${ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME}'\"\\n
\\n'$(cat ./${ATTACHMENT_FILE_TO_READ_FROM_DISK})'
\\n--NextPart--"}' > "$tmp_message"

aws ses send-raw-email --region us-east-1 --from sender@gmail.com --destination file://$tmp_destination --raw-message file://"$tmp_message"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `jq` to verify your json is fine

```
#! /bin/bash

echo '{\"Data\": 
"Subject:'${SUBJECT}'\\n
MIME-Version: 1.0\n
Content-type: Multipart/Mixed; 
boundary=\"NextPart\"\\n\\n--NextPart\\n
Content-Type: text/plain\\n\\n'${BODY}'
\\n\\n--NextPart
\\nContent-Type:'${ATTACHMENT_TYPE}';
\nContent-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=\"'${ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME}'\"\\n
\\n'$(cat ./${ATTACHMENT_FILE_TO_READ_FROM_DISK})'
\\n--NextPart--"}' > "$tmp_message"

if jq < "$tmp_message"; then
    aws ses send-raw-email --region us-east-1 --from sender@gmail.com --destination file://"$tmp_destination" --raw-message file://"$tmp_message"
else
    echo "ERROR" >&2
fi
```